# icon glyphicon not displayed in bootstrap4 angular

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm a beginner in angular, i want to display glyphicon-search glyphicon icon but i can not, i'm using angular5 bootstrap 4

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<h1>fffff</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check that you installed bootstrap 4 or included package into header

Comment: Include package